# How to edit eps file to change fonts?

Tags: image, fonts, eps

I have some eps files that I'm using as figures in a paper, and I'd like to change the fonts used. I need to convert all "Type-3" fonts to "Type-1" fonts. Is there a way I can edit the eps files directly and change the fonts used?

Comment: What do you mean by directly? Using some script? Or using e.g. Photoshop. If the latter I would suggest move the question to e.g.: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Inkscape can edit EPS. You can export the fonts as path objects and not worry about them at all.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by 'not worry about them at all'? Can I change the fonts used in the figure?

Comment: @Big Dogg: great question, I am struggling with exactly the same problem right now. Did you find a nice solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Christoph I saw your comment almost 2 years too late, but for future Googlers I've come across a couple of solutions since I asked this question: 1) You can use Ghostscript to convert fonts in PDF figures directly, 2) on a Mac, you can "save to PDF" in Preview on the entire document, which will convert all fonts to Type-1 with the appropriate settings.